# Node express + MongoDB - get with param

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I' m trying to create get call with parameters. So far I've created get which returns the whole JSON from MongoDB:

```
router.get('/movies', function (req, res, next) {

    var movies = req.db.get('movies');
    movies.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});

    });
});
```

How can I create get which will return only these movies from some certain year or title or movies from certain year but only those which are dramma type?

I was trying with:

```
router.get('/movies/:title', function (req, res, next) {

    var title = res.title;

    var movies = req.db.get('movies');
    movies.find({title: title}, function (err, docs) {
        res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});
    });
});
```

But Postman returns empty object.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: res.title doesn't make much sense. res is the response, anything sent with the request will be on req.

Comment: Probably you meant `req.params.title`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only those *movies from some certain year or title* or *movies from certain year but only those which are "drama" type*, you would need to define your REST API in such a way that you pass a list of values as URL request parameters that can then be used as the filter.

For example, if you test your API with the URL:

```
http://your.api.com/movies?title=foo
```

the router will get only those movies with the `title = "foo"`.

If you use this URL for the GET request:

```
http://your.api.com/movies?year=1996
```

the router gets only those movies from the year 1996.

The URL

```
http://your.api.com/movies?year=1996&type=drama
```

gets only those movies from the year 1996 AND those which are of drama type.

In your router implementation, use the [**`req.query`**](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route as your **[`find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find)** query. If there is no query string, it returns an empty object, `{}` which by default if used in the **[`find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find)** method will return all available movie documents in the collection. Thus your router will have something like this:

```
router.get('/movies', function (req, res, next) {

    var movies = req.db.get('movies'),
        query = req.query;

    // convert year parameter string to int if it exists 
    if (query.hasOwnProperty("year")){
        query["year"] = parseInt(query.year);
    }
    movies.find(query, function (err, docs) {
        res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});    
    });
});
```

Comment: @camel Where exactly are you not quite understanding?

Comment: this one works fine:
router.get('/movies/production', function (req, res, next) {
    var production = req.params.production;
    var movies = req.db.get('movies');
    movies.find({production: production}, function (err, docs) {
        res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});
    });
});
but this not:
router.get('/movies/production', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = req.query.production;
    var movies = req.db.get('movies');
    movies.find(query, function (err, docs) {
        res.json({length: docs.length, records: docs});
    });
});

Comment: And if I have in my get integer (router.get('/movies/year') it doesn't work at all. I get lost

Comment: If you design your API in such a way that your URL requests are structured as `http://your.api.com/movies?year=2001` then `var query = req.query` object has the value `{year: 2001}` that you can then pass on as your `find()` query document, as explained in the opening paragraph of the answer.

Comment: So if you try the router implementation as I have done in the answer, you can test the API with the following URLs: `http://your.api.com/movies?title=foo` to test for getting movies of certain title, or `http://your.api.com/movies?year=1996` to test only those movies from some certain year or `http://your.api.com/movies?year=1996&type=drama` to test only those movies from some certain year but only those which are `drama` type.

Comment: @camel I have edited my answer by adding a bit more clarity, let me know if the concept is still unclear.

Comment: Thaaaaaanks a lot, I get it! I thougth that I need to create seperate call for different params. So basically I need one router.get('/movies', ....) with one var query = req.query. And depending on URL I can retreive data with different conditions. One  more annoying think is that I need over and over kill my npm and run npm start. Is there something I can do to avoid re-running npm?

Comment: `http://your.api.com/movies?title=foo,bar,zoo` How can I translate this to `find{title:{$in: ["foo", "bar", "zoo"]}}`

Comment: @ArthurBrito Change your query string parameter in the route to `http://your.api.com/movies?title[]=foo&title[]=bar&title[]=zoo` and your mongo query would simply be `find({ 'title': { '$in': req.query.title } })`